# Javascript using CSS to rotate element

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following code

```
function rotateRabbitHead(rabbit_head){
    var bunny = document.getElementById(rabbit_head);
    bunny.style.transition = "left 1s ease-in 0s";
    bunny.style.left = "0px";
    bunny.transform = "rotateX(10deg)";
}
```

I trigger the function onclick and see the rabbit head come into view but I can't get the head to rotate or put a time on the transform.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You're missing the `.style` part: `bunny.style.transform`. I've voted to close this as a typographical error.

Comment: link to a working example: http://blog.geneticcoder.com/?s=rotate+transition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bunny.style.transform = "rotateX(10deg)";
```

You forgot the `.style` :)

If i may, please consider adding this for multiple browser support

```
// Code for Chrome, Safari, Opera
bunny.style.WebkitTransform = "rotate(10deg)"; 
// Code for IE9
bunny.style.msTransform = "rotate(10deg)"; 
// Standard syntax
bunny.style.transform = "rotate(10deg)";
```